# Validation Group inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Given the following classes and interfaces

```
class Person {

  @NotNull(groups=Both.class)
  private String name;
}
```

Validate groups:

```
interface One {}
interface Two {}
interface Both extends One, Two {}
```

When calling

```
Person person = new Person();

validator.validate(person, One.class)
```

or

```
validator.validate(person, Two.class)
```

I would expect that it should be invalid since name is null but it does not.
It turns out the group Both.class is only useful when used in validator.validate(..., Both.class) method.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @hooknc I would expect that it should be invalid since name is null but it does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got the inheritance in the wrong direction. The `Both` group extends `One` and `Two` You might think about it as "`Both` contains `One` and `Two`". That means that, everytime you validate against the `Both` group, all the constraints of groups `One` and `Two` are also contained into `Both`, and are thus validated.

But the inverse is not true: a constraint belonging to the group `Both` is not part of `One`, and is not part of `Two` either. So, if you validate the constraints of group `One`, constraints belonging to Both won't be validated.

See http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence-groupinheritance for the reference.

Comment: Thanks! 
If I have a lot of groups (A,B,C,D,E,F.class) I have to list them all in annotation @NotNull (groups = {A,B,C,D,E,F.class})? 
Not good.